# Unity | Use AR and VR in the same app but not simultaneously

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm using Unity 2019.4.5f1 and I have to create an app where the user can use AR and VR but not simultaneously.

- For the AR section I'm using ArFoundation and it works fine
- For the VR section I'm using [Google Cardboard XR Plugin for Unity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart)
  but it doesn't work.

I think the problem is that ArFoundation is asking me to use OpenGLES3 while the VR plugin is asking me to use OpenGLES2. If I select only OpenGLES2 the build fails, if I select only OpenGLES3 the build is ok but the app crashes.

I think I can use the old [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/get-started-android) but it is deprecated since Unity 2019.3 and both Unity and Google suggest to use the new Google Cardboard XR Plugin but I can find no documentation and no people that use it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, that's the problem old google vr sdk, try something else like unity xr which works for large vr platform like oculus.